# Java Error : Not a statemenr for accessing unassigned class member variable

Tags: java, compiler-errors

For below piece of code,

```
class Test {
    int i;
}


public class Testable {
    public static void main(){
         new Test().i;   
    }
}
```

I am getting 'error: not a statement' for line **new Test().i;**

Comment: What do you intend that line to do? You just "mention" a field and don't *do* anything with it (i.e. read from it or write to it).

Comment: I wanted to print default value for i and i compiled it before putting it into print statement and got the error hence was wondering why this is not a valid statement. Now I understood that valid statement should be either an expression or any function such as in this case either read or write.

Answer (score 1):

`new Test().i` is indeed not a statement. You need to do something with this expression, like, e.g., saving it to a variable:

```java
int i = new Test().i;
```